# location of exe file in nuget package and matching file tag in nuspec

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, .net-5, nuspec

Currently I am manually creating a nuget directory structure, nuspec and pack it with the commandline (nuget.exe).

My problem is an exe file that is intended to be added to the output directory of projects referencing it. The exe is a plug-in loader and the referencing project is the plug-in. When the plug-in is defined as start project the exe should be started.

I just can't get it working that the exe from the nuget is placed into the output directory.

The exe is placed under contentFiles/any/net5.0/the.exe

The nuspec contains the following tag

```
<contentFiles>
  <files include="any/net5.0/the.exe" buildAction="None" copyToOutput="true" />
</contentFiles>
```

If I define BuildAction as Content the compiler complains it's a binary instead of a text file (CS2015)

Any idea what would work?

Answer (score 0):

For those who stumble accross the requirement to pack and distribute an .exe (which isn't a tool) via a nuget package.

The structure within the nuget needs to be:

- the `the.dll` needs to be in the `lib/net5.0` (or equivalent depending on your code)
- the following files need to be placed in the `content` and `contentFiles/any/any` directory

  - `the.exe`
  - `the.pdb`
  - `the.xml`
  - `the.runtimeconfig.json` (not sure about that but without it the exe doesn't start)

---

Within the generated nuget the nuspec would look like:

```
<metadata>
   <contentFiles>
      <files include="any/any/the.exe" buildAction="None" copyToOutput="true" />
      <files include="any/any/the.pdb" buildAction="None" copyToOutput="true" />
      <files include="any/any/the.xml" buildAction="None" copyToOutput="true" />
      <files include="any/any/the.runtimeconfig.json" buildAction="None" copyToOutput="true" />
    </contentFiles>
  </metadata>
```

---

The content files will show up in Visual Studio under the project root (except the dll).

The distributed exe than could be started as shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70122780/external-executable-not-starting-with-error-the-target-process-exited-without-r).