# External executable not starting with error "The target process exited without raising a CoreCLR started event"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, .net-5

I created a class library project and configured the properties section debug to start an exe (the.exe) located in the output directory of the build (as shown in the image).

It worked as long as we had a pre-build event copying the exe and all related files from one directory in the output directory of the build. Unfortunatly this is inconvinient and we do not have track which version of the exe is used.

So I created a versioned nuget package to place all the files in the output directory. I confirmed all the required files (I know of) are in the output directory. And since I created the nuget package manually with the CLI I can confirm they are exactly the same files.

But when I try to start the application from Visual Studio 2019 now I get the following error in the debug output:

```
The target process exited without raising a CoreCLR started event. Ensure that the target process is configured to use .NET Core. This may be expected if the target process did not run on .NET Core.
The program '[16616] the.exe' has exited with code -2147450749 (0x80008083).
```

Actually both (the.exe and the class library) are .NET 5.

Comparing the changes of the two setups via Git changes does not hold any clues beside adding the nuget and removing the pre-build events.

So any clue what could be the difference/problem and how to get the executable running? May I missed something?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Well, better check twice when you are stating "I confirmed all the required files (I know of) are in the output directory."

The problem was that not all files made it into the output directory.

In my case only the the.exe and the.dll were placed into the output directory. Once I checked again and ensured that also the.runtimeconfig.json (which was missing) were added it was running again and the exception were gone. Though I am not sure if there is a better way than distributing the.runtimeconfig.json.